# How to change cell value based on today's date in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, setvalue

I have a table like this one, but I'm looking to automate the change of status when a given date is reached. I've looked into setValue(), but I still need your help to make it work : I'm more or less desperately trying to write something that will change 'Status' to 'Terminated' when today's date match with the one in 'End'.

[image]

Thank you for your help!!!

Comment: What is juil or fevr?

Comment: In your situation, unfortunately, from your sample image, I cannot understand that whether your date is the date object, and also I cannot understand the columns and rows. So, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet? By the way, in your situation, how is the values of "End" edited?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try, assuming status in in column A and end date in column C

```
function myFunction() {
  var d = new Date()
  var f = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Feuille 1')
  for (var i = 2; i <= f.getLastRow(); i++) {
    if (f.getRange(i, 3).getValue() - d < 0){
      f.getRange(i,1).setValue('Terminé')
    }
  }
}
```